# How can I import a package from a local PyPI which requires authentication using PyCharm?

Tags: python, authentication, pycharm, local, pypi

## Introduction

I've uploaded a python package up to a local PyPI inside Artifactory. I've installed it on my system with `pip install foo` (I need to authenticate). I can do `python -c "import foo"` without any issue.

When I try to make use of this module inside PyCharm (with `import foo`), PyCharm throws me `unresolved reference 'foo'`.

So I went into Preferences->Project:myproject->Project Interpreter->Available Packages->Manage Repositories and added the local PyPI as shown below:

[image: Manage Repository window with local Pypi added]

but when reloading the package list in the 'Available Packages' I get the following error dialog:

[image: Error dialog displaying "Packages - Error loading package list:Request failed with status code 401"]

401 forbidden makes since since I was never prompted for credentials, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

## Question

How can I import package `foo` inside a PyCharm project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't support authentication for custom package repositories, please vote for the corresponding ticket in the IDE's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26556

Meanwhile, you should be fine installing the package from the terminal on the interpreter used as a project interpreter in PyCharm (**Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter**).

Answer (score 1):

Update to this.  With version 2021.1, it looks like if you set the PIP_INDEX_URL environment variable to your Artifactory repo containing your credentials (username and API Key), you can use the "View -> Tool Window -> Python Packages" tool to install packages from your Artifactory PyPi repo.  So, you would do something like:

```
PIP_INDEX_URL=https://<Artifactory Username>:<Artifactory API Key>@mycompany.jfrog.io/mycompany/api/pypi/pypi-org-remote/simple
```

Or whatever the URL is to your Artifactory pypi repo.  For whatever reason, you can install from the "Python Packages" tool window, but you cannot use the "Setting -> Projects -> Python Interpreter" to install packages.

Comment: where should I set the environment variable?

Comment: This is not working for me.